# Enable mhchem mathjax extension

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax, mhchem

[Mathjax 2.0 supports the `mhchem` extension](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/whats-new-2.0.html#many-new-tex-additions-and-enhancements). Could we enable it? It will save us lots of time in typesetting chemical formulae.

[How to enable the extension](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/tex.html#tex-extensions)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The chemistry extension has been enabled - let us know if you see any issues.

Comment: Would it be easy to make the font inside `\ce` environments a bit smaller to bring it in line with the default font on the site? The extension is great for chemical equations, but the inline formulas look a bit out of place using a different font and being larger than the rest of the text.

Comment: Do you have an example @MadScientist - please provide a link.

Comment: In [this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7/why-does-nitration-yield-a-meta-product-in-this-reaction) and one of the answers you can see inline chemical formulas, they are noticeably bigger than the surrounding text. Though, on looking at it a bit more it's probably the different font that makes them stand out so much.

Comment: @geoff Mhchem isn't loading on the mobile site :/

Comment: @Mad doesn't _all_ mathjax look too big?